# How to access object data

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects received from Django view function through AJAX call. This array contains posts and other information such as pagination. This array as follow:

```js
[{
  "id": 191,
  "user": {
    "username": "engsalehalomari",
    "id": 1
  },
  "category": 4,
  "sub_category": 49,
  "title": “first post ",
  "content": "first post detail",
  "date_updated": "Apr 06, 2020, 15:47 p.m"
}, {
  "id": 190,
  "user": {
    "username": "saleh",
    "id": 1
  },
  "category": 4,
  "sub_category": 49,
  "title": "second post",
  "content": "second post detail",
  "date_updated": "Apr 06, 2020, 13:26 p.m"
}, {
  "id": 189,
  "user": {
    "username": "saleh",
    "id": 1
  },
  "category": 4,
  "sub_category": 49,
  "title": "third post",
  "content": "third post detail",
  "date_updated": "Apr 06, 2020, 13:23 p.m"
}, {
  "id": 188,
  "user": {
    "username": "saleh",
    "id": 1
  },
  "category": 4,
  "sub_category": 49,
  "title": "fourth post",
  "content": "fourth post detail",
  "date_updated": "Apr 06, 2020, 13:22 p.m"
}, {
  "id": 187,
  "user": {
    "username": "saleh",
    "id": 1
  },
  "category": 4,
  "sub_category": 49,
  "title": "fifth post",
  "content": "fifth post detail",
  "date_updated": "Apr 06, 2020, 13:14 p.m"
}, {
  "id": 186,
  "user": {
    "username": "saleh",
    "id": 1
  },
  "category": 4,
  "sub_category": 49,
  "title": "sixth post",
  "content": "sixth post detail",
  "date_updated": "Apr 06, 2020, 12:38 p.m"
}, {
  "id": 185,
  "user": {
    "username": "saleh",
    "id": 1
  },
  "category": 4,
  "sub_category": 49,
  "title": "seventh post",
  "content": "seventh post detail",
  "date_updated": "Apr 06, 2020, 12:37 p.m"
}, {
  "id": 184,
  "user": {
    "username": "saleh",
    "id": 1
  },
  "category": 4,
  "sub_category": 49,
  "title": "eight post",
  "content": "eigth post detail",
  "date_updated": "Apr 06, 2020, 12:35 p.m"
}, {
  "id": 183,
  "user": {
    "username": "saleh",
    "id": 1
  },
  "category": 4,
  "sub_category": 49,
  "title": “ninth post ",
  "content": "ninth post detail",
  "date_updated": "Apr 06, 2020, 12:34 p.m"
}, {
  "id": 182,
  "user": {
    "username": "saleh",
    "id": 1
  },
  "category": 4,
  "sub_category": 49,
  "title": "tenth post",
  "content": "tenth post detail",
  "date_updated": "Apr 06, 2020, 12:20 p.m"
}, {
  "posts": {
    "current_index": 2,
    "start_index": 11,
    "end_index": 20,
    "posts_count": 65
  }
}, {
  "result": "success"
}]
```

How can I get the value of `current_index` inside of `posts` inside of this array using jQuery? Keep in mind the number of `posts`, which is 10 here + two objects for further information, might be different. Thus, this array objects vary from time to time.

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this. That's a tool primarily for amending the DOM. To access the properties of an object/members of an array you need plain JS

Comment: Is `posts` always contained in the second to last item in the array?

Comment: Thank you Rory. Can you show me how can I do it in pure javascript ?

Comment: Yes, it does exist in the second to last item in the array

Comment: I added an answer for you. Also note that the first object is using an invalid `"` character, as you can see from the syntax highlighting in the question. You'll need to correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your assertion in the comments that the target object is always the second to last in the parent array, then you can access it by index:

```
let currentIndex = data[data.length - 2].posts.current_index;
```

```js
let  data = [{
  "id": 191,
  "user": {
    "username": "engsalehalomari",
    "id": 1
  },
  "category": 4,
  "sub_category": 49,
  "title": "first post",
  "content": "first post detail",
  "date_updated": "Apr 06, 2020, 15:47 p.m"
}, 
/* Lots of other objects... */
{
  "id": 182,
  "user": {
    "username": "saleh",
    "id": 1
  },
  "category": 4,
  "sub_category": 49,
  "title": "tenth post",
  "content": "tenth post detail",
  "date_updated": "Apr 06, 2020, 12:20 p.m"
}, {
  "posts": {
    "current_index": 2,
    "start_index": 11,
    "end_index": 20,
    "posts_count": 65
  }
}, {
  "result": "success"
}];

let currentIndex = data[data.length - 2].posts.current_index;
console.log(currentIndex);
```